# "Cannot insert object" Error when inserting PDF files/objects into Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, pdf

I am currently using microsoft excel 2010. Trying to insert some PDF files into the spreadsheet.

I cliked Insert Tab -> Object -> select Adobe Document (Checked the Display as icon checkbox) from the list -> Go on to the "Create from file" tab -> Select the pdf file from my computer (Checked display as icon) -> press the OK button
Then the following error appear in a dialogbox: 
"Cannot insert object".

Other Objects (such as other excels and words) and Pictures can be inserted without problem.

Tried the following, and did NOT help at all:

- Reopen excel spreadsheet
- Delete the file MSForms.exd from any Tempsubfolder in the user's profile
- Delete all the MS Office updates
- Delete all the files end with .exd

Comment: if you reproduce the problem then check event viewer > application you should see an entry for Appcrash. if this is adobe just repair it. you will need to restart excel and then try it again but also don't click "link to file" check box this should work. also check the file for special characters and also make sure it hasn't got a super long name. the name length also includes the folder names too there's a limitation there. good luck

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finially I figured out a way to solve this PDF attachment problem on excel: Select a Package instead!

Go to Insert Tab -> Object -> double click Package in the list of options -> then the "Create Package" dialog will appear where it will guide you through the attachment process!

It even allows you to rename the file name of the attachment.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

Usually it is because you still open the pdf file. Make sure the pdf file you were trying to insert is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Task Manager, close the the current process running for inserting object.

For instance- if you want to insert .doc file. In task manager, under processes close app "Microsoft word". It would work & let you insert the .doc file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.